# Regular Expression not matching period delimited phrase

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

I have a list of words that contains the following patterns:

```
$Age
$Address.Street
$Job.Salary.Value
```

Where `$` is an object (like `Person.Age`, or `Person.Address.Street`)

I already have a RegexPattern, but it's getting only the first word.

My regex is:

```
(?<!\w)[@,#,$]\w+
```

In `$Address.Street`, it brings to me only `$Address`, it's missing the remainder content `.Street`

What is wrong with it? Why it's bringing to me only:

```
$Address
```

instead

```
$Address.Street
```

or

```
$Job.Salary.Value
```

*not only* `$Job`

Comment: Helpful regex tip: Characters in `[` character classes `]` don't need to be comma-separated - or *anything*-separated. `[@#$]` will do just fine.

Comment: Good point; have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\w doesn't capture the '.' character. Try:

```
(?<!\w)[@#$][\w.]+
```

instead.

Comment: hello what does ?<!\w do ?